# dump file where is monitor.wait entry point? and how i can find the reason of wait?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, .net-core, windbg, dump

in the following dump file

> windbg !dumpstack

where is monitor.wait entry point?

and how i can find the reason of wait?

and the function that causes the wait?

i'm sure that wait is happening here but i cant find my way through the dump file

which function the wait is happening on?

how can i further investigate the reason of the wait?

is there any resource or tutorial on finding the reason of this kind of wait?

```
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+14    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+ef    
coreclr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+fe    
coreclr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+7d    
coreclr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+7f    
coreclr!SyncBlock::Wait+194    
[[GCFrame]]    
coreclr!ObjectNative::WaitTimeout+d4    
[[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ] (System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait)] System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean, Int32, System.Object)    
System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)+398    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)+b9    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)+1a2    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+25    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary)+3c    
AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__86.MoveNext()+2c2    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__86, fkzqs1mt.znn]](<ExecuteAsync>d__86 ByRef)+45    
AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()+7e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__14.MoveNext()+367    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__14, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor]](<RenderPageAsync>d__14 ByRef)+4d    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext, Boolean)+ac    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__13.MoveNext()+a6    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__13, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor]](<RenderAsync>d__13 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()+2e5    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__18, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures]](<ExecuteAsync>d__18 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.IView, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionary, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Int32>)+cc    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.IView, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult)+8a    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()+e5    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures]](<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()+88    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__30, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core]](<InvokeResultAsync>d__30 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State ByRef, Scope ByRef, System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)+1351    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()+b0    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core]](<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync()+84    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State ByRef, Scope ByRef, System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)+128e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()+b0    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core]](<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()+84    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State ByRef, Scope ByRef, System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)+583    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()+1f3    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core]](<InvokeAsync>d__20 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAsync()+9b    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()+2e4    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing]](<Invoke>d__4 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext()+68    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2, NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware]](<Invoke>d__2 ByRef)+45    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+83    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext()+68    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2, NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware]](<Invoke>d__2 ByRef)+45    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+83    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext()+68    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase+<Invoke>d__2, NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware]](<Invoke>d__2 ByRef)+45    
NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+83    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+21b    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()+2e1    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<Invoke>d__18<System.__Canon> ByRef)+7e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+b9    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()+2e1    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<Invoke>d__18<System.__Canon> ByRef)+7e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+b9    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()+2e1    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<Invoke>d__18<System.__Canon> ByRef)+7e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+b9    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()+2e1    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__18[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<Invoke>d__18<System.__Canon> ByRef)+7e    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+b9    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()+2a6    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+<Invoke>d__9, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session]](<Invoke>d__9 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()+1c9    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing]](<Invoke>d__4 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()+76    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics]](<Invoke>d__6 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+8f    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()+ba    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics]](<Invoke>d__3 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()+3c5    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+<Invoke>d__8, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration]](<Invoke>d__8 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()+205    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting]](<Invoke>d__3 ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)+89    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Context)+39    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1+<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting]].MoveNext()+63e    
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1+<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel]](<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2<Context> ByRef)+45    
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting]].RequestProcessingAsync()+ad    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].InnerInvoke()+9b    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+49    
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+97    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)+23e    
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)+a2    
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+1e2    
coreclr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83    
coreclr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+14e    
coreclr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+38    
coreclr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+2df    
coreclr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+234    
coreclr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+161    
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]    
coreclr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+7b    
coreclr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+8e    
coreclr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+188    
coreclr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+8b    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21
```

Answer (score 0):

Monitor.Wait is called within ManualResetEventSlim.Wait.

The ManualResetEventSlim class does some spinning while it is waiting for an event to be set and will call Monitor.Wait if the event isn't set while it is polling/spinning.

A quick scan of your stack trace it looks like you waiting on a async task to be completed.   Here is where the waiting looks to begin .. Just follow the stack traces (dump stack objects to find and further analyze the bolded task being passed in or !clrstack -a  might get you some more parameter and locals information).

```
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)+1a2    
            System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(**System.Threading.Tasks.Task**)+25    
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary)+3c    
            AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__86.MoveNext()+2c2    
            System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__86, fkzqs1mt.znn]](<ExecuteAsync>d__86 ByRef)+45    
            AspNetCore._Areas_Article_Views_Article_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()+7e
```

Comment: Clrstack -a dosent show locals even sosex didnt help(im a newbie) how do i dump stack objects any tutorial or help?

Comment: How do i find what is waiting for?

Comment: It's waiting on task to complete/signal
!mdso is sosex
!dso  sos

You want to find the System.Threading.Tasks.Task  object being passed and begin analyzing/dumping  (!mdt  sosex ,  !do sos) that to see what the task is doing (i.e. it may have an action/delegate to dump to see a function the task is running) 
I do not know of any specific tutorial for thread tasks but one of my first tutorials 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/07/07/managed-debugging-with-windbg-introduction-and-index/

I also read Clr via C#  awesome book

Use 
!sos.help and !sosex.help  for commands